# Is there a way to randomize the letters in my string?

Tags: python, string

I have been trying to create a random password generator with user input for a few hours now, but when the code is printed, it is not how I would like it. I have been trying to use the "random" code in python but it is not working.

```
word1=input("Input first word:")
characters = "123456789"
while len(word1) < 6:
  word1=input("Remember, your word has to be 6 letters long. Try again: ")
  if not len(word1) < 6:
    break
word2 = input("Input second word:")
while len(word2) < 6:
  word2 = input("Remember, your word has to be 6 letters long. Try again: ")
  if not len(word2) < 6:
    break
word3 = input("Input third word:")
while len(word3) < 6:
  word3 = input("Remember, your word has to be 6 letters long. Try again: ")
  if not len(word3) < 6:
    break
password = []
allpass = word1 + word2 + word3 + characters
for i in list(allpass):
  password.append(allpass)
print(choice(password))
```

Let's say if the user inputted, "pizzaburger", "hamburger", "motorcar". I would like the program to print that out with the letters in the strings randomized.
I am sorry for the vague description but this is the best description I can give.

Comment: ``choice`` is ``random.choice``? As in "Return *a* random element from the non-empty sequence seq."? If you want to "shuffle [a] sequence and return a new shuffled list, use ``sample(x, k=len(x))`` instead."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shuffle` method from `random` to shuffle elements of a list. In your case to use it simply convert string to list, shuffle it and merge the shuffled list back to a string. It can be done like this:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> def scramble_string(input_string):
...     char_list = list(input_string)
...     shuffle(char_list)
...     return "".join(char_list)
...
>>> sample_words = "this" + "is" + "very" + "cool" + "test"
>>> scramble_string(sample_words)
'ceitstyhoevrisstlo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `random.shuffle()`:

```
import random

string = list('pizzaburgerhamburgermotorcar')
random.shuffle(string)
print(''.join(string))
```

Output: `hragbueiecmrubaromprzzgotarr`